# How do I use my HTTP handlers for selected paths and MVC handler for the rest?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, httphandler

I have an MVC2 application. I also have a set of ready HTTP handlers that derive from `System.Web.IHttpHandler`. How do I use them together?

I tried the following in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <!--other stuff-->
        <handlers>
            <add name="MyCustomHandler" verb="GET" path="MySpecificPath*" type="CustomHandling.CustomHttpHandlerBase, CustomHAndlingAssembly"/>
            <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>
        </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

yet control never reaches my handler and MVC handler is used for all requests.

How do I use my handler for one specific path and MVC handler for all other paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you need to ignore those specific paths from routes collection in application start. For example,

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("MySpecificPath/{*pathInfo}");
```

Otherwise [UrlRoutingModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutingmodule.aspx) will match with the route and then http handler will be located via `IRouteHandler` for that route.

See [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) for more info about mixing ASP.NET WebForms with ASP.NET MVC .